# compute sha-256 using chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a code to compare sha-256 value from the file and artifactory which throws error if the checksum does not match. But I want to compute checksum in my own recipe rather than reading it from artifactory. Below is the code I have so far and trying to find out if there are any functions or methods which I can use in my recipe to compute sha-256 for a file.
Thanks in advance

````
  only_if { node['abc'] }
  not_if { ::File.exist?(checksum_file) and ::File.read(checksum_file).strip==coordinates['checksum'].strip }
  message 'The previously deployed checksum is not aligned with the actual value'
  level :debug
  notifies :create, 'remote_file[download file]', :immediately
end```
````

Answer (score 0):

chef is built on top of ruby, so we can unleash the power of ruby within recipes.

if you would like to compute the sha-256 checksome for a file, the following ruby code might be handy

```rb
require 'digest'
Digest::SHA256.file('/path/to/file').hexdigest
```

the snippet in your post, does not specify which chef resource are you using, although it feels like you are using the the [`log`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_log.html) resource.

since you mentioned that you are interested in downloading the file from artifactory, [`remote_file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) resource can do that and it has a `checksum` property:

> `checksum`: Optional, see `use_conditional_get`. The SHA-256 checksum of the file. Use to prevent a file from being re-downloaded. When the local file matches the checksum, Chef Infra Client does not download it.

Comment: I tried the below code but it is throwing ERROR: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen. `remote_file 'compute checksum' do only_if { ::File.exist?(node.run_state['path']) } checksum Digest::SHA256.file('/tmp/xyz.zip').hexdigest end`

Comment: @shriBin: please update your original post and i will update my answer accordingly